# can't install/update apps on my android phone

Tags: google-play-store, updates, samsung-galaxy-ace-3

My *Galaxy Ace 3* (GT-S7272) keeps restarting after updating the apps and removing the app after restarting. Here's what I did to solve the problem but no hope:

- I tried clear factory reset and clearing the cache but it didn't work.
- I tried to install the apks of the apps without google play but it didn't work.
- I tried to clear the cache and remove the data of google play app but it didn't work.

What should I do now as the phone doesn't accept any new apps nor updating the current ones ?

Comment: I don't get any error messages , just restarting . and the SD card I didn't remove it from the mobile while installing/updating the apps.

Comment: and my android version is 4.2.2